# Issue with Pinia where the state value remains unchanged upon the initial call to an asynchronous action

Tags: vue.js

pinia：

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { TempGetService } from '@/api/bmu'
// 设备ID模块
export const useBmuStore = defineStore('bmu-id', () => {
  const bmu_id = ref(8)
  const BmuTemperatureList = ref([])
  const SetBmuTemperatureList = async () => {
    const res = await TempGetService(bmu_id.value);
    BmuTemperatureList.value = res.data.temperature;
  }
  const SetBmuid = (id) => {
    bmu_id.value = id;
  }
  const GetBmuTemperatureList = () => {
    return BmuTemperatureList.value;
  }
  return {
    bmu_id,
    BmuTemperatureList,
    SetBmuTemperatureList,
    SetBmuid,
    GetBmuTemperatureList
  }
})
```

Parent component：

```
import TempertureSp from '@/components/TempertureSp.vue';
import HeatMap from '@/components/HeatMap.vue';
import { useBmuStore } from '@/stores/modules/bmu';
const bmuStore = useBmuStore();
bmuStore.SetBmuTemperatureList()
setInterval(() => {
  bmuStore.SetBmuTemperatureList()
},1000)
```

Child component：

```
import * as echarts from 'echarts';
import { useBmuStore } from '@/stores/modules/bmu';
import { onMounted} from 'vue';
const bmuStore = useBmuStore();
const TempGet = () => {
  const data = [];
  console.log(bmuStore.BmuTemperatureList);
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      data.push([i, j])
    }
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < bmuStore.BmuTemperatureList.length; i++) {
    data[i][2] = bmuStore.BmuTemperatureList[i]
  }
  return data;
}

onMounted( () => {  
  const xAxisData = ['1', '6', '11', '16', '21', '26', '31', '36', '41', '46']
  const yAxisData = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
  const HeatMap = echarts.init(document.getElementById('HeatMap'));
  const data = TempGet();
  setInterval(()=>{
    TempGet()
  },1000)
  const options = {
    color: ['#00f2f1'],
    tooltip: {
      position: 'top',
      formatter: function (params) {
        return (
          params.marker +
          (params.dataIndex + 1) +
          '#' +
          '<br>' +
          '温度' +
          ' : ' +
          params.value[2] +
          '℃'
        )
      }
    },
    grid: {
      left: '0%',
      top: '0%',
      right: '0%',
      bottom: '4%',
      containLabel: true
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'category',
      data: xAxisData,
    },
    yAxis: {
      type: 'category',
      data: yAxisData,
    },
    visualMap: {
      show:false,
      min: 5,
      max: 65,
      calculable: true,
      orient: 'horizontal',
      left: '10%',
      top: '2%',
      inRange: {
        color: [
          '#313695',
          '#4575b4',
          '#74add1',
          '#abd9e9',
          '#e0f3f8',
          '#ffffbf',
          '#fee090',
          '#fdae61',
          '#f46d43',
          '#d73027',
          '#a50026'
        ]
      }
    },
    series: [
      {
        data: data,
        name: 'heatmap',
        type: 'heatmap',
        label: {
          show: true
        },
        emphasis: {
          itemStyle: {
            shadowBlur: 10,
            shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  HeatMap.setOption(options);
  window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    HeatMap.resize()
  })
})
```

Issue：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLrEQ.png)

The parent component is looping and calling asynchronous methods in Pinia to set the value of BmuTemperatureList, while the child component is looping to retrieve the current value of BmuTemperatureList. However, when I first load the page, the value of the BmuTemperatureList array is empty.

Why is the initially printed value an empty array?

Comment: Most likely: It’s async and you don’t await it so the code will continue running through and the result will be updated at some point. The child is rendered before the call finishes. Also since Vue has actual reactivity you shouldn’t have a child component poll for data from the store.